# JavaScript - One var 3 shapes

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I'm learning javascript right now so I'm still new at this. I have an image I drew in an HTML canvas. They are the same size but to reduce the code i was wondering if it's possible to turn one in a var and just adjust the position of the second one?

heres my code:

```
                // Cloud 1
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
                ctx.ellipse(320, 170, 38, 25, 0 * Math.PI/180, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                ctx.ellipse(340, 156, 32, 35, 0 * Math.PI/180, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                ctx.ellipse(368, 174, 32, 26, 0 * Math.PI/180, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                ctx.ellipse(390, 174, 32, 26, 0 * Math.PI/180, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                ctx.ellipse(392, 173, 30, 26, 0 * Math.PI/180, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                ctx.fill();

                // Cloud 2
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
                ctx.ellipse(720, 100, 38, 25, 0 * Math.PI/180, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                ctx.ellipse(740, 86, 32, 35, 0 * Math.PI/180, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                ctx.ellipse(768, 104, 32, 26, 0 * Math.PI/180, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                ctx.ellipse(790, 104, 32, 26, 0 * Math.PI/180, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                ctx.ellipse(792, 103, 30, 26, 0 * Math.PI/180, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                ctx.fill();
```

Comment: Ok, maybe I didn't explain what I was hoping to do. basically, I'm trying to turn cloud 1 into a var so I can place it somewhere else multiple times if need be. Now I don't know if that even possible. I've never seen a var with shape's code inside of it.

Comment: See my answer. You can put your cloud1 drawing code in a function (so you don't need to repeat it) and then use `context.translate(offsetX,offsetY)` to reposition multiple cloud1s anywhere on the canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var clouds =  [];

clouds.push({x: 320, y: 170});

clouds.push({x: 324, y: 156});

....

.... 


for (cloud = 0; cloud <10; cloud++){
    ctx.ellipse(clouds[cloud].x, clouds[cloud].y, 30, 26, 0 * Math.PI/180, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current image data of the canvas and put it back in a different place:

```
var data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
ctx.putImageData(data, deltaX, deltaY);
```

Where deltaX and deltaY are how much you want to move your image horizontally and vertically.

In your case deltaX is 400, deltaY is -70.